# Check whether a feature class is registered as versioned using Python

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

How can I check whether or not a feature class is versioned using Python?

I'm trying to register feature classes using a python script. Before I do this I need to check whether a feature class is versioned. Are there keywords that we can use in coding while looping through the feature classes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you call the method arcpy.Describe() on your feature class - e.g. arcpy.Describe("path/to/my/feature/class"), you will get a Dataset properties object. You can then use the isVersioned property of this object to get a boolean, whether or not your dataset is versioned.

Code snippet:

```
import arcpy
datasetVersioned = arcpy.Describe("path/to/my/feature/class").isVersioned
```

Remember to use escaped backslash characters, forward slashes, or a raw string in the path

More details in the docs: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Dataset_properties/000v0000002m000000/