# Is there a way to check if data was versioned using "move edits to base" option?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

Is there a way to check if data was versioned using "move edits to base" option?

Preferably through ArcGIS itself or using Python, but any way will work.

*EDIT*

Is there way to see if this box was checked when versioning the data:

[image]

Comment: please explain further.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to explain much more. I added a screenshot of when the option is selected.

Comment: There's only a way to determine if a feature class is *currently* in Move Edits to Base, not how the data was originally collected.

Comment: Okay, how do I determine that? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-click on the Feature Class in question using ArcCatalog or Catalog window in ArcMap.  View the Feature Class Properties.  Under the General tab there is a Versioning section which will contain your answer. Example when option to move to base is checked:

[image: Feature Class Properties]

Comment: Do you know if I can access that via Python?

Comment: Best I have found is the previous post: [How to check whether a fc is registered as versioned or not using python](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16936/how-to-check-whether-a-fc-is-registered-as-versioned-or-not-using-python).  It will return a Boolean True/False for your feature class and does not distinguish between checked/unchecked option to 'move edits to base'

Comment: Here is a link to an ESRI Tech article which does the save as above regarding [HowTo:  Programmatically determine if feature classes are versioned](http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40610).  Still only gives you True/False but can help you write a script to iterate through many feature classes and write them to a log file.