# Is there a way to test if a feature class is registered with geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, esri-geodatabase

I've got feature classes inside an Oracle 11g ArcSDE geodatabase.

I'd like to perform the arcpy method RegisterWithGeodatabase_management on all those feature classes.
But before that, I'd like to test if the feature class is already registered, as the registration method will return an error in that case.

How can I test if a feature class is registered with geodatabase or not?

Comment: I've just answered the same question here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81639/how-to-determine-using-python-whether-arcsde-table-is-registered-with-geodatabas

Comment: Isn't there a simpler procedure?

Comment: Sure.  Just catch and ignore the "already registered" error.